# Java - How to limit the number of threads running at once when creating them in a for loop

Tags: java, multithreading, limit

I'm making a proxy checker and I've made a previous one and it was multithreaded but it created a new thread for each proxy to check, thats what I was doing with this one but when I went to use it to check 60k proxies it nearly melted my pc lol. I've tried to limit the amount of threads running at once but no luck. The way I originally did it was like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < proxies.size(); i++){
    final String s = proxies.get(i);
    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(s.split(":")[0], Integer.parseInt(s.split(":")[1])));
            if(checkProxy(proxy, 5000))
                textArea_1.setText(textArea_1.getText() + s + "\n");
            progress++;
            progressBar.setValue(progress);
        }
    }.start();
}
```

The way I tried to limit was by having a global variable which incremented for each new thread then minused itself for the end of each new thread thinking that the loop would pause and wait for the variable to be low enough to create a new thread like so

```
for(int i = 0; i < proxies.size() && runningThreads <= 5; i++){
    runningThreads++;
    final String s = proxies.get(i);
    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(s.split(":")[0], Integer.parseInt(s.split(":")[1])));
            if(checkProxy(proxy, 5000))
                textArea_1.setText(textArea_1.getText() + s + "\n");
            progress++;
            progressBar.setValue(progress);
            runningThreads--;
        }
    }.start();
}
```

I'm currently out of ideas so any help would be great.

Comment: Why not remove `&& runningThreads <= 5` from the for loop and just have an if in the loop instead `if (runningThreads <= 5) { make a new thread }`? Then only increment `i` if you make a thread.

Comment: Why not use a fixed thread pool? Also, if that progress bar is a Swing JProgressBar, then your code is ignoring Swing threading rules by making Swing calls off of the EDT. This can lead to intermittent but pernicious program-halting exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

You could use something like this:

```
Semaphore s = new Semaphore(5);
for (int i = 0; i < proxies.size(); i++) {
  s.acquire();
  new Thread() {
    public void run() {
      try {
        ...proxy stuff...
      } finally {
        s.release();
      }
    }
  }.start();
}
```

The semaphore has 5 "permits", which means that the first 5 calls to `s.acquire()` will succeed immediately. But after that, `s.acquire()` can only succeed if there has been a corresponding `s.release()`. The number of permits goes down by one (`s.acquire()`) just before every thread start, and back up by one (`s.release()`) just before every thread exit. Since the number of permits can never be negative, the number of threads that have started but not yet exited can never be more than 5.

You could also use [Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-) to explicitly make a thread pool of size 5. If the number of tasks can be really big then with thread pools you have to think about limiting the number of tasks that can be queued up, perhaps using a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). The above solution with semaphores doesn't have this problem, because it doesn't queue anything up.

Answer (score 1):

Hovercraft Full Of Eels answered this question with FixedThreadPool's, I dont know how to make a comment an answer so I just answered myself and gave him credits. I just made a Class that extended Thread and put my proxy checking code inside the `run()` method of the class then where my old code was I replaced it with this.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()));
for(int i = 0; i < proxies.size(); i++){
    final String s = proxies.get(i);
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(s.split(":")[0], Integer.parseInt(s.split(":")[1])));
    Thread thread = new CheckThread(proxy, 5000, i);
    executor.execute(thread);
}
executor.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the for loop into a while loop.

```
while (true) {
    while (runningThreads <= 5) {
        runningThreads++;
        final String s = proxies.get(i);
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(s.split(":")[0], Integer.parseInt(s.split(":")[1])));
                if(checkProxy(proxy, 5000))
                    textArea_1.setText(textArea_1.getText() + s + "\n");
                progress++;
                progressBar.setValue(progress);
                runningThreads--;
            }
        }.start();
    }

    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

The outer `while (true)` loop will keep the check running and create new threads if the running threads fall below 5.